# Get other div child element class list

Tags: jquery

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="structure">
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="divOne">
        <input type="text" class="class01 myClass01" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="divTwo">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sub-items</legend>
            <div>
                <div class="divTwoButtons">
                    <a class="divTwoButton" href="javascipt:void(0);">GET THIS WRAP INPUT CLASSES</a>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div><!-- end wrap -->

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="divTwo">
        <input type="text" class="class02 myClass02" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="divTwo">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sub-items</legend>
            <div>
                <div class="divTwoButtons">
                    <a class="divTwoButton" href="javascipt:void(0);">GET THIS WRAP INPUT CLASSES</a>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div><!-- end wrap -->
</div><!-- end structure -->
```

What I'm trying to do is: Each WRAP has the same structure. And when user clicks the "DIVTWOBUTTON" link, I want to get the class of the input that is located inside the same WRAP div.

I have to use $(this) and cannot use class names because they're dynamic.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, use `.closest('.wrap')` and then `.find('input')` assuming that there would be only one `input` tag inside each `.wrap`.

See the demo below

```js
$('.divTwoButton').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('.wrap').find('input').prop('class'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="structure">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="divOne">
      <input type="text" class="class01 myClass01" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="divTwo">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Sub-items</legend>
        <div>
          <div class="divTwoButtons">
            <a class="divTwoButton" href="javascipt:void(0);">GET THIS WRAP INPUT CLASSES</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end wrap -->

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="divTwo as">
      <input type="text" class="class02 myClass02" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="divTwo">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Sub-items</legend>
        <div>
          <div class="divTwoButtons">
            <a class="divTwoButton" href="javascipt:void(0);">GET THIS WRAP INPUT CLASSES</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end wrap -->
</div>
<!-- end structure -->
```